# onclick event when part of highcharts funnel is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can i create an onclick handler when a part of the Highcharts funnel is clicked?

I tried to follow the documentation, but none of the events seem to work for me.

I've tried `click` (below) `drilldown`, and `selection`. click is the only one that fires, but it only does when the background is clicked, not the actual funnel pieces.

This is their example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/funnel/

```
$('#id').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'funnel',
        marginRight: 100,
        events: {
            click: function (event){
                console.log(event);
            }
        }
    },
    title: {....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this bro!!
Reference http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.events.click

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
                    softConnector: true
                },
                neckWidth: '30%',
                neckHeight: '25%',
                events: {
                    click: function (event){
                      console.log(event);
                    }

                //-- Other available options
                // height: pixels or percent
                // width: pixels or percent
            },
```

Comment: +1 to you as well! worth to explain a little what is changed and stuff, anyhoo! gist is `events --> click` event call, `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your click event handler inside `plotOptions.series` like the following snippet and **[this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3j01py5/)** adaptation of the demo you linked to:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    console.log(event);
                    alert(event.point.name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yo! ++1 to you, nice one! gist is `events --> click` event call `:)`

Answer (score 1):

**Woking demo**: `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/tts4kqdk/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/8m7fjzqd/

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.events.click
- APi reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.events

so within the tree you just need to add `events: --> click` rest detail is in the high chart link above.

Rest should fit your needs. `:)`

**code**

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    alert('HULK --> ' + event);
                }
            },
            type: 'funnel',
            marginRight: 100
        }, ...
```

**working screenshot**

[image]

Comment: That doesn't fire when you click on one of the colored parts of the funnel.. at least not for me

Comment: yep, gist is tree event driven between `events --> click` will +1  you as well